# Generate CSV with fixed header with data from foreach

Tags: php

I would like to generate a CSV file with fixed header (name, email, cod) from data which is coming from a foreach loop. Here is what I tried, but it's not working yet:

```
$parcels = array();

$parcels = array('name','email', 'cod');

foreach ($orders as $order_id) {
      $order_info = $this->model_sale_order->getOrder($order_id); 
       
      $parcels[] = $order_info['shipping_firstname'] . ' ' . $order_info['shipping_lastname'],
      $parcels[] = $order_info['email'],
      //if empty write null, else write value
      $parcels[] = empty($this->request->post['cod'][$order_id]) ? '' : $this->request->post['cod'][$order_id],
}

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
foreach ( $parcels as $line ) {
    $val = explode(",", $line);
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$line` doesn't contain a "line", but a "cell".

You need a multidimensionnal array, if you want to store all data in memory before to write the file.

You could store in an array in your loop, and add it in `$parcels`.

```
$parcels = [['name','email', 'cod']]; // first line

foreach ($orders as $order_id) {
      $order_info = $this->model_sale_order->getOrder($order_id); 

      $line = [];
      $line[] = $order_info['shipping_firstname'] . ' ' . $order_info['shipping_lastname'];
      $line[] = $order_info['email'];
      //if empty write null, else write value
      $line[] = empty($this->request->post['cod'][$order_id]) ? '' : $this->request->post['cod'][$order_id];

      $parcels[] = $line; // add the line into `$parcels`
}


foreach ( $parcels as $line ) {
    // no need to explode here
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
}
```

NB: Caution, you have some `,` at the end of somes lines, which must be `;`.

---

You could also do it in one loop :

```
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
fputcsv($fp, ['name','email', 'cod']);
foreach ($orders as $order_id) 
{
    $order_info = $this->model_sale_order->getOrder($order_id); 
     
    $line = [];
    $line[] = $order_info['shipping_firstname'] . ' ' . $order_info['shipping_lastname'];
    $line[] = $order_info['email'];
    //if empty write null, else write value
    $line[] = empty($this->request->post['cod'][$order_id]) ? '' : $this->request->post['cod'][$order_id];
  
    fputcsv($fp, $line);
}
fclose($fp);
```

See [working example](https://3v4l.org/0IpWg)